# apache/php symlink 403 permission forbidden

Tags: php, apache, symlink

I have my project sitting in: **dev/php/project**.
My system apache2 server folder is: **/var/www/html/**.

And my goal is to reach this address: **localhost/project/file.php**.

So I have created symlink in /var/www/html folder like so:

```
sudo ln -s dev/php/project /var/www/html/project
```

and after this if I try to open localhost/project url. I get 403 forbidden error. I searched alot and saw that others have had same issues. So I tried to follow how to fix guides and none of them helped.

All of the guides say that I should chmod the symlink, but when I try to excecute this command:

```
sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www/html/*
```

or directly:

```
sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www/html/project
```

I get:

```
chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink '/var/www/html/project'
```

I have also tried to use other chmod modules ( dont know how to call them correctly, sorry) like 777, x+o, and everything I came across . I also tried to create symlink with one php file but the outcome was the same.

Can someone please help me understand what the problem is? I cant move forward because of this issue. I am ready to quickly respond to answers, questions.

Comment: Where does the dev folder exists in your path? Is it on root (/)?

Comment: its in /home/user/dev/php/project

Comment: on which path did you run the `sudo ln -s` command?

Comment: i ran chmod on /home/user/dev/php/project ( earlier i ran it on dev/php/project). and it worked! now i can access the file from localhost. 

do you know why I had to do it like so?